# Does a subpanel ground need to be insulated wire

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I am installing a 60amp subpanel and want to ground the panel to a grounding rod. I have 8awg non insulated copper and want to know if it can be used for this or does it need to be insulated. It will travel through wood framing to the exterior for ground.

Answer (score 2):

No insulation is required.  However grounding to a rod is not enough, you must also run a ground wire back to the supply.

Dirt is a poor conductor and you can't expect it to return the 100 amps + that it must to assure a breaker trip during a ground fault.  When it can't, it will not trip and leave a condition where all your grounds are energized at line voltage.

Comment: Than-you. I do have the ground wire connected back to the main panel. I wanted to add another ground to ensure there is no potential at the subpanel. I wasn’t sure if it needed to be insulated though.

Answer (score 1):

The wire you are talking about does not need to be insulated.